# Indexing in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I wanted to find a way to add a string into the middle of emails in Google sheets. For example:

We have 5 rows:

```
bus@email.com

car@email.com

truck@email.com

train@email.com

plane@email.com
```

I want to change these emails to this form:

```
bus+test@email.com

car+test@email.com

truck+test@email.com

train+test@email.com

plane+test@email.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your list of e-mails is on column A, use the following formula to achieve the desires result:

```
=substitute(A1,"@","+test@")
```

You might want to copy & paste as text depending on how you will use the e-mails.